# Intermediate Jacobian of abelian varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, hodge-theory

Is the intermediate Jacobian of an abelian variety again an abelian variety?

Comment: If $H^{2p-1}(X)$ has nonzero Hodge numbers only of type $(p-1,p), (p,p-1)$, then the corresponding intermediate Jacobian is an abelian variety, but otherwise it is not usually true. In particular, if $X$ is a general abelian variety, and $1<p<\dim X$, I would expect that the answer is no.

Comment: @DonuArapura Thank you for the comment. The abelian variety I have in mind is the product of Jacobians of a curve.

Comment: Even so, I would expect that when $X$ is a Jacobian of a general curve, it would fail for  $p$ as above.